# Cannot add object to NSMutableArray using @interface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, the app (iphone ios5) wil crash when executing "addStatus:statusObj" ?

```
id<Statuses> statusObjects;
statusObjects = [Status singleton];

id<Statuses> statusMessagesObjects;
statusMessagesObjects = [[Status singleton] copy];
StatusObj *statusObj = [[StatusObj alloc] init];
statusObj.date = [NSDate date];
[statusMessagesObjects addStatus:statusObj];
StatusObj *tmpObj = [statusMessagesObjects getStatusAtIndex:0];
DebugLog(@"-- debug -- %@", tmpObj.date);
```

---------------------------------------header files----------------------------------

```
@interface Status : NSObject <Statuses, NSCopying>
{
    NSMutableArray* status;
    NSString* path;
}

+ (id) singleton;

@property (copy) NSString* path;

- (void) addStatus:(StatusObj*)statusObj;
- (void) deleteStatusAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (StatusObj*) getStatusAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (int) count;
- (void)save;
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone; 

@end


@protocol Statuses <NSObject>

@required
- (void) addStatus:(StatusObj*)statusObj;
- (void)deleteStatus:(StatusObj *)statusObj;
- (void) deleteStatusAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)deleteAllStatuses;
- (StatusObj*) getStatusAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (int) count;
- (void)save;

@optional
- (void)moveStatus:(StatusObj *)statusObj toIndex:(NSUInteger)newIndex;

@end
```

Comment: The object you are adding looks ok. Most likely the mutable array that you want to add to is nil. Please debug this and maybe post the crash log

Comment: You should show the code where the Status object is initialized. Also, what kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks really strange and your naming convention are unconventional , why did you copy your Singleton?

I have edited your maybe that could help, but it will be helpfull if you post your implementation.

```
id<Statuses> status;
status = [Status singleton];

StatusObj *statusObj = [StatusObj new];
statusObj.date = [NSDate date];

[status addStatus: statusObj];

StatusObj *tmpObj = [status getStatusAtIndex:0];
DebugLog(@"-- debug -- %@", tmpObj.date);
```

Comment: I found out my self sorry for the uncunvionent